# Python failure file handling freeze

Tags: python, linux, file, raspbian

I am using a python script to transfer the contents of three files to a different three files. The original files are data from three thermometers I have connected to an RPI running raspian. All the script is supposed to do is take the contents of the files and move them so that I can have another program (ComScript) read and parse them.

My problem is that if one or more of the thermometers is disconnected before the script starts, it freezes. It doesn't freeze if I disconnect a thermometer while the script is running.

Here is the code

```
import time
a = 1
while a == 1:
 try:
    tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000004d2ca5e/w1_slave")
    text = tfile.read()
    tfile.close()
    temperature = text



    tfile2 = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000004d2fb20/w1_slave")
    text2 = tfile2.read()
    tfile2.close()
    temperature2 = text2


    tfile3 = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000004d30568/w1_slave")
    text3 = tfile3.read()
    tfile3.close()
    temperature3 = text3



    textfile = open("/home/pi/ComScriptPi/profiles/Temperature_parse/w1_slave1", "w ")
    textfile2 = open("/home/pi/ComScriptPi/profiles/Temperature_parse/w1_slave2", "w ")
    textfile3 = open("/home/pi/ComScriptPi/profiles/Temperature_parse/w1_slave3", "w ")
    temperature = str(temperature)
    temperature2 = str(temperature2)
    temperature3 = str(temperature3)
    textfile.write(temperature)
    textfile2.write(temperature2)
    textfile3.write(temperature3)
    textfile.close()
    textfile2.close()
    textfile3.close()
    print temperature
    print temperature2
    print temperature3
    time.sleep(3)

 except:
  pass
```

I added the exception pass because I need it to keep running even if it gets bad values. WHen one of the thermometers is disconnected the file python is trying to read is blank, but still there.

Comment: Are you expecting `a` to not equal 1 at some point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the blanket except.

Your script is *not* freezing, but any error you get is being ignored in an endless loop. Because you use a blanket `except:` you catch **all** exceptions, including the keyboard interrupt exception `KeyboardInterrupt`.

At the very least **log** the exception, and catch only `Exception`:

```
except Exception:
    import logging
    logging.exception('Oops: error occurred')
```

`KeyboardInterrupt` is a subclass of `BaseException`, not `Exception` and won't be caught by this except handler.

Take a look at the [`shutil` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) for copying files, you doing way too much work:

```
import time
import shutil
import os.path

paths = ('28-000004d2ca5e', '28-000004d2fb20', '28-000004d30568')

while True:
    for i, name in enumerate(paths, 1):
        src = os.path.join('/sys/bus/w1/devices', name, 'w1_slave')
        dst = '/home/pi/ComScriptPi/profiles/Temperature_parse/w1_slave{}'.format(i)
        try:
            shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
        except EnvironmentError:
            import logging
            logging.exception('Oops: error occurred')

    time.sleep(3)
```

Handling files should only *ever* raise `EnvironmentError` or it's subclasses, there is **no** need to catch everything here.

Comment: Thank you and Ill try this, but why does python stop printing the data im telling it to in the script, and why does the computer start working really hard.

Comment: @user2631867: That's because you have an infinite loop. Even the `time.sleep(3)` call is skipped so the loop keeps the CPU busy.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and I will try the fix above tomorrow, but the infinite loop is on purpose. I have run this script for over a month without undo cpu consumption. Even without the sleep command it ran fine. Today I added the bit with the exception so that python wouldn't fail when I yanked a thermometer. I thought that this would simply ignore errors and keep cycling through the script. Was I wrong?

Comment: It does ignore errors, but it ignores keyboard interrupts too, because it catches too much. Any errors send it in a tight loop because the `time.sleep()` is then skipped as well. Catch *less* (just `EnvironmentError` is enough), log errors so you know what goes wrong, and keep the `sleep` outside if the `try`.

Comment: also in the code you gave me is that slash supposed to be in the third file name in paths =

Answer (score 0):

The open of the unplugged device is most likely blocking because the device driver won't open if the device is not present.

You'll need to use os.open which is the equivalent of the Unix system call "open" and specify the flag O_NONBLOCK and check the return code. You can then use os.fdopen to turn the return value of os.open into a normal Python file object.

Comment: This won't cause the CPU to go into overdrive and the fan to come on. See the comment below my answer; the code is in an infinite loop.

Comment: No it won't. But it is a likely factor also.